# Shortest s-t Path with a covering constraint

Tags: graph-algorithms, co.combinatorics, network-modeling

> **Instance**: an undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ with edge-weights $w:E\to{\mathbb{R}}$;
>   a source $s\in V$ and a sink $t\in V$;
>   a ground set $X=\{x_1, ..., x_k\}$, and for every $v\in V$ a corresponding subset $X(v)\subseteq X$.
>
> **Objective**: Find a minimum weight $s$-$t$-path for which the subsets 
>   on its path verties cover $X$.

Has this problem been studied before in combinatorial optimization?

Comment: Your problem contains the TSP-path problem as a special case, as the subsets can be used to enforce that the path visits every vertex in the graph.

Comment: @Gamow Thank you for your comments. Maybe Hamiltonian Path with s and t as end vertices is more precise? In general, each feasible path is a subset Hamiltonian Path with s and t as ends. But it looks like enumerating all such subsets is expensive.

Comment: Let's assume the graph is complete and unweighted, thus the shortest distance between any two vertices is 1. Then, this problem can be seen as the Minimum Set Cover Problem, it is already very difficult as by Dinur & Steurer's result,  it cannot be approximated to (1-o(1) )ln n, unless P =NP.

Comment: Since edge weights can be negative in the above formulation, you can use the same reduction to show that it's NP hard to distinguish between the case where OPT=0 and when OPT>0, so there's no hope for a multiplicative factor approximation algorithm. Assuming you're more interested in the positive weight case, do you have an idea of what kinds of paths you're most interested in (simple paths, edge non-repeating paths / trails, walks, etc.)?

Comment: @YonatanN This problem is motivated by network applications, I am interested in the simple path in this case. Thank you!

Comment: In the case of simple paths, doesn't @Gamow's response rule out any hope of an approximation algorithm? If one can't solve the feasibility problem in the first place, one can't expect to find a feasible solution with good approximation guarantees.

Comment: This problem is clearly at least as hard as TSP as you can set X=V and set X(v)=v. But there is a closely related problem, called subset TSP problem wherein we have a small set X and X(v) is either empty or v. There are several papers on it and if your X is small you can have a look at it. We also covered a similar related problem, called waypoint routing problem, that might also be beneficial for you to have a look at it (there we concern about shortest walks not simple paths).